# Why is this the energy of an electron in the conduction band?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

In Kittel's solid state book he says that:

$$\epsilon_k=E_c +\dfrac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m_e}$$

is the energy of an electron in the conduction band, where $E_c$ is the energy at the conduction band edge and $m_e$ the effective mass of the electron.

Now, I've been trying to understand this. By definition, the effective mass of the electron is

$$\dfrac{1}{m_e}=\dfrac{1}{\hbar^2}\dfrac{d^2\epsilon}{dk^2}.$$

So that

$$\epsilon_k-E_c=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d^2 \epsilon}{dk^2}k^2.$$

This would be true if this were the taylor expansion of $\epsilon$ around $k=0$, if at $k=0$ we had $d\epsilon_k/dk=0$ and if $\epsilon_k(0)=E_c$.

I just can't understand why all of this is true. Why this epansion for $\epsilon$ in the conduction band is true? How is the edge of the conduction band related to $k=0$?

Comment: from symmetry in an isotropic medium the kinetic energy must be an even function of $k$

Answer (score 1):

The energy-wave vector relation given in your first equation is the 2nd order Taylor expansion approximation at the bottom of the conduction for the simplest case of a direct semiconductor with a spherical symmetric conduction band around a minimum in k-space at $\vec k=o$ and energy $E_c$. In general, there are multiple (equivalent) minima of the conduction band at symmetric positions $\vec k≠0$ in k-space and there are direction-dependent inverse effective masses (inverse effective mass tensors) describing the  2nd order Taylor expansions at these minima giving ellipsoids for the surface of equal energy there. Examples for semiconductors with a minimum at $k=0$ are III-V compounds like InSb, GaAs, InAs, InP,... Multiple conduction band minima at $\vec k≠0$ are found in the important group IV semiconductors Si and Ge.